# need an idea to migrate a task from jquery to jquerymobile (for newbie)

Tags: jquery

I had completed a task using jquery - drupal.

In this page jquery and Ajax plays a vital role.

Jquery Events like drag and drop, preview, creating new box and Ajax events like Editing description and search takes place there..

**Now the problem is, some functionality like drag and drop are not working on tablets and ipad.**

What should i do to resolve this issue ?

I know this question may not be specific.. But as i am a newbie I need  some general ideas to resolve this issue....

Answer (score 1):

I have heard good things about: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI only listens to mouse events. jQuery UI Touch Punch maps touch events to their analog mouse events, enabling jQuery UI on touch devices. See http://touchpunch.furf.com for more info.